# iOS PushKit ring phone

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, pushkit

I'm developing a VoIP app with Apple's PushKit. I am able to receive notifications when the app is in background or even when it's not running. However, I don't know how to turn on the display and ring the phone when it's necessary, like in case of incoming VoIP call.

Comment: Is your problem resolved? then close this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule local notification, with push kit or anything never you app will come foreground, never phone will turn on.

With use of local notification you can set sound file for 30 seconds.

You can repeat at every 30 seconds until user act on local notification.

Local notification could have action buttons.